# Custom development pod does not install any files into my Pods project

Tags: cocoapods

I have a git repo in this format:

```
MyApp/
  Podfile
  ....
TestHelperPod/
  Classes/
    .h & .m files
  TestHelperPod.podspec
```

My podfile in the MyApp folder has a line that looks like so:

```
pod 'TestHelperPod', :path => '../TestHelperPod'
```

and my podspec's source_files pattern looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  //...
  s.source_files  = "TestHelperPod/Classes/*.{h,m}"    
end
```

When i do a `pod spec lint` on the podspec, it seems to succeed and picks up all the classes in the `Classes` directory to build them. However when I actually try to `pod install` in MyApp, the Pods project is not generated with references to the classes in the `Classes`directory. This used to work when the `Classes` directory was also named `TestHelperPod` and the source_files pattern was `TestHelperPod/**/*.{h,m}`, but I don't want the repetition in the folder structure there. The pattern with ** in it doesn't work with this new structure either. Any ideas? I'm running the latest version of cocoapods at the time of writing, 0.32.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out; changing the source_files line to this:

```
s.source_files  = "Classes/*.{h,m}"
```

Worked; the documentation on cocoapods.org suggested that the source files pattern must be at the top of the repo which is why i thought I needed TestHelperPod in there, even though the podspec was already in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I am not able get the swift files inside the project . Below code worked for me .

`s.source_files = 'Podname/Podname/**/*.{h,m,swift}'`

adding swift along with h,m made it work .

NOTE: install the pod again after updating podspec file .